# Comparing multiple fields of ArrayList using Lambda API and collecting the objects

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, grouping

I am facing a situation similar to described below in my project, of which I am unable to implement the code.

I have a POJO Class

```
    public class TranObject {

        public String loadId;
        public String vDate;
        public String dDate;
        public String pDate;

        public TranObject(String loadId, String vDate, String dDate, String pDate) {
            super();
            this.loadId = loadId;
            this.vDate = vDate;
            this.dDate = dDate;
            this.pDate = pDate;
        }
      //Getter and Setters
      //toString()

 }
```

Now I have another processor class where I want to implement some comparison between tranload objects that I am receiving through a data service call and collect them into another collection.
**The implementation logic is given in the comments below. Please read the below comments**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DemoClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TranObject> listObj = Arrays.asList(
                new TranObject("LOAD1", "20180102", "20180202", null),
                new TranObject("LOAD2", "20180402", "20180403", null),
                new TranObject("LOAD3", "20180102", "20180202", "20190302"),
                new TranObject("LOAD4", "20180402", "20180403", null),
                new TranObject("LOAD5", "20200202", "20200203", null)
        );

        /*
        IF (obj1, obj3 vdate and dDate are equal)
                IF(pDate == null for obj1 or obj3)
                    THEN obj1 and obj3 are equal/duplicates, and we collect them.
                ELSE IF(pDate != null for obj1 and obj3)
                    IF(pDate is same for obj1 and obj3)
                        THEN obj1 and obj3 are duplicates, and we collect them.
                    ELSE
                        THEN obj1 and obj3 are unique.
         */
    }
}
```

My End result should be a collection like List containing duplicate Tran objects for further update.

I searched internet in order to how to solve it using Lambda API.
-> Tried using groupingBy first with vDate and then dDate, but then I could not compare them for pDate equality.

Can anyone help me solve this issue. A little help will be very helpful for me. I am stuck here

**UPDATE:**
After some reading I am trying to implement the same by over-riding equals method in POJO class as shown below:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean isEqual=false;
        if(obj!=null) {
            TranObject tran = (TranObject) obj;
            isEqual=(this.vDate.equals(tran.getvDate()) && this.dDate.equals(tran.getdDate()));
            if(isEqual && this.pDate != null && tran.getpDate()!= null) {
                isEqual = (this.pDate.equals(tran.getpDate()));
            }
        }
        return isEqual;
    }
```

Still it's not working as expected... Can anyone please help me why??

Comment: What if obj1,obj2 are one set of duplicates and also obj3,obj4 are seperate set of duplicates, what should be the ouput.

Comment: Then in that case, I want all those four objects in that duplicate list collection. In above case, obj1 obj2 obj3 and obj4 are the total duplicate records; so I want all four in the final collection.

Comment: Given the conditions and sample input, it's not really clear what would happen if more than two such records are grouped using `vDate` and `dDate`? e.g. add `TranObject obj6 = new TranObject("LOAD6", "20180102", "20180202", null);
        listObj.add(obj6);`

Comment: @New2Java Related to the *update* in the question, overriding equals needs hashcode implementation override as well.

Comment: @New2Java - That line "INCASE of obj1 and obj3..." looks like a duplicate of the previous line "CHECK IF pdate for both of these...". Please remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `TranObject` needs an `equals` and `hashCode` method.

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  //check instanceof and self comparison

  TranObject other = (TranObject) obj;


  if(this.vDate.equals(other.vDate) && this.dDate.equals(other.dDate)) {
    //if pDate is not given then consider them duplicate
    if(this.pDate == null || other.pDate == null)
      return true;

    //if pDate are the same then they are duplicate, otherwise they are unique
    return this.pDate.equals(other.pDate);
  }

return false;

}

//auto generated by Eclipse
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + ((dDate == null) ? 0 : dDate.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((pDate == null) ? 0 : pDate.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((vDate == null) ? 0 : vDate.hashCode());
  return result;
}
```

Now that you have an equals method to determine if two `TranObjects` are considered equal (based on the rules you specified), just collect the elements that occur in the list more than once:

```java
private static List<TranObject> collectDuplicates(List<TranObject> list) {
  List<TranObject> result = new ArrayList<TranObject>();

  for(TranObject element : list) {
    if(Collections.frequency(list, element) > 1) 
      result.add(element);
  }

  return result;

}
```

This will return all elements that have a duplicate.

Note: `collectDuplicates` does not return a *unique* list of the elements that are duplicated. Instead, it returns a list of each duplicated element (as required by OP's question).

Comment: Consider using `Objects.hash(dDate, pDate, vDate)` for hashCode and implements correctly equals (eg: `if (other == this) return true; if (!(other instanceof TranObject)) return false` and finally use `Objects.equals` to compare date and check nulls as in `return Objects.equals(dDate, other.dDate) && Objects.equals(pDate, other.pDate) && Objects.equals(vDate, other.vDate)`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest to your requirement would be grouping in a nested manner and then filtering the inner `Map` for varied conditions while being interested only in values eventually.

```
Stream<Map<String, List<TranObject>>> groupedNestedStream = listObj.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> Arrays.asList(a.vDate, a.dDate)
                , Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.pDate == null ? "default" : t.pDate)))
        .values().stream();
```

from these groupings further the conditions for the values (from map) to be eligible are

1. they all have same `pDate` in this case the innerMap would have just one entry with the common `pDate`  (`m.size() == 1`)
2. one of the values after grouping has exactly one `pDate` as `null`  (meaning `m.containsKey("default") && m.get("default").size() == 1`)

```
List<TranObject> tranObjects = groupedNestedStream
        .filter(m -> m.size() == 1 || (m.containsKey("default") && m.get("default").size() == 1))
        .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note, the use of `"default"` string constant to avoid failures(or poor practice) in collecting a `Map` with `null` keys or values.

Comment: Hey Naman, thanks for the solution.I implemented it and to me, yeah it looks like the result I want. Just one question though, Is there any way I can eliminate the LOAD5 transaction object from this list? I can not think of a way for doing that.

Comment: @New2Java It depends. Based on what conditions do you want to perform that exclusion?

Comment: Meanwhile, can you please help me understand this part of code!!                                 List<TranObject> tranObjects = groupedNestedStream
          .filter(m -> m.size() == 1 || (m.containsKey("default") && m.get("default").size() == 1))
          .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @New2Java updated the answer with the `filter`ing logic explained in detail